# My android application crashes when login

Tags: java, android, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm using the Facebook Unity SDK 6.1 to submit my score on Facebook and I already could do that, but I have a bug when I try to login: I press the login button, the native Facebook app opens asking me for permissions, I press okay, and when it returns to my app, my app simply crashes. When I open it again, I'm already logged and everything works fine. I've tried to fix this issue for weeks, but I can't get rid of it. The worst part is it only happens in some devices.

Here are the logs:

```
E/dalvikvm(17369): Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorNotification

W/dalvikvm(17369): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 40 (Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;

D/dalvikvm(17369): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0030

D/dalvikvm(17369): VFY: dead code 0x0032-0077 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.showErrorNotification (ILandroid/content/Context;)V

W/InputManagerService( 1751): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 17306 uid 10138

I/ActivityManager( 1751): Displayed com.FoxyGames.FoxyFox/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity: +11s188ms (total +11s305ms)

I/ActivityManager( 1751): Displayed com.FoxyGames.FoxyFox/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity: +11s215ms

D/AndroidRuntime(17369): Shutting down VM

W/dalvikvm(17369): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d578)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): Unity version     : 4.5.5f1

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): Device model      : Sony Ericsson ST25i

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): Device fingerprint: SEMC/ST25i_1261-7887/ST25i:2.3.7/6.0.B.3.184/R7P_zw:user/release-keys

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): 

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.FoxyGames.FoxyFox/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2553)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2595)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:121)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:973)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at com.facebook.unity.FBLogin.onActivityResult(FBLogin.java:245)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity.onActivityResult(FBUnityLoginActivity.java:25)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2549)

E/AndroidRuntime(17369): ... 11 more

W/ActivityManager( 1751):   Force finishing activity com.FoxyGames.FoxyFox/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity

W/ActivityManager( 1751): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40c25ed8 com.FoxyGames.FoxyFox/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity}

W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 1880): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback

D/CustomizationProvider( 1833): openFile -- START uri=content://com.sonyericsson.provider.customization/settings/com.sonyericsson.textinput.uxp

I/CustomizationProvider( 1833): No configuration file: /system/etc/customization/settings/com/sonyericsson/textinput/uxp/custom_settings.xml

W/kernel  ( 1487): [52845.270385] prcmu_kick_a9wdog: kicking ID 0

W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC( 1880): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
```

I think this is the important line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=64206, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.FoxyGames.FoxyFox/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException**
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Hey Fede :) Welcome to SO. Thank you for your first question. I would love to help but I don't know that platform unfortunately.  I did look over your post and correct some syntax in it and a couple of typos :).  It might be a good idea to edit it and add what you tried so far. It would help whoever's trying to help you have more info on your issue

Comment: This is the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926466/facebook-unity-sdk-login-very-slow-and-sometimes-crashes